# Java and environment variables on Windows

Tags: java, windows, spring, tomcat, environment-variables

I use:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${PROJECT_CONFIG_PATH}/project.conf" />
```

in my applicationContext.xml to get local config (one for development and another for production). `PROJECT_CONFIG_PATH` is a system environment variable (not eclipse env).

It works: on Windows in Eclipse (Jetty) and on Unix.

It doesn't work: on Windows with Tomcat 6 (`java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${PROJECT_CONFIG_PATH}\project.conf`)

Could someone please tell me why Tomcat on Windows doesn't see environment variables? And how could this be solved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Tomcat is being run as a service, you will need to use the tomcat configuration editor to set the variable.

Start->Programs->Apache Tomcat x.x->Configure Tomcat

Select the Java tab
Add the variable under "Java Options" as:

```
-DPROJECT_CONFIG_PATH="c:/yourpath"
```

Click OK and then restart the tomcat service.

Comment: Thanks! That works. But System.getenv("PROJECT_CONFIG_PATH"); still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I should have pointed out that it would be System.getProperty("PROJECT_CONFIG_PATH"); To use an environment variable, I suspect you would have to set an environment variable for the service user under which tomcat is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/PROJECT_CONFIG_PATH/project.conf" />
```

Comment: No. The idea is that the config file is not on the classpath. This file should be on the file system and in different locations for different environments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Tomcat's startup batch files inherit the parent environment. Not sure why, though.

Try setting `PROJECT_CONFIG_PATH` in either catalina.bat or startup.bat in the Tomcat bin directory.